# nginx resolves wrong host

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have two nginx configs.
Server game.yii resolve first and always displayed.

```
server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         set $host_path "/srv/http/game";
         #access_log  /www/mysite/log/access.log  main;

         server_name  game.yii;
         root   $host_path;
         set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

         charset utf-8;

         location / {
             index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
         }

         location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
             deny  all;
         }

         location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
             try_files $uri =404;
         }

         location ~ \.php {
             fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

             set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
             if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
                 set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
             }

             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

             fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
             fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
         }

         location ~ /\. {
             deny all;
             access_log off;
             log_not_found off;
         }
     }

    # You may add here your
    # server {
    #   ...
    # }
    # statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

    ##
    # You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
    # of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
    #
    # Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
    # file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
    #
    # Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
    ##







server {
    listen 80;

    root /srv/http/lightproject;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name lightproject;
        set $light "index.php";

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
       index  index.html $light;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /$light?$args;
        }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #

        location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        set $fsn /$light;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
        }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

and /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   lightproject
127.0.0.1   develop
127.0.0.1   game.yii

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

When I go to url: http://lightproject/
resolve game.yii project path

How to rewrite virtual hosts for the right host to resolve?

Comment: Try changing `listen 80 default_server;` to             `listen 80;`

Comment: Unindented code. Removed Russian comments.